# Clean way to filter through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is snippet from a library of mine for handling an API. I'm curious about an alternative (potentially cleaner), or more pythonic way to write my filter_entries function.

```
def json_from_url(url):

    from urllib2 import urlopen
    import json

    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

class netdb:
    """ Class construct for portal"""

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.json = json_from_url(url)

    def filter_entries(self, names=[], sites=[], regions=[], vendors=[], models=[], live=True, output='json'):
        """ Function to pull devices down from portalAPI based off filters """

        netdbDevices = dict(self.json)

        if names: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if device['name'] in names]
        if sites: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if device['site']['dns_prefix'] in sites]
        if models: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if device['name'].split("-")[0] in models]
        if vendors: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if device['vendor']['name'] in vendors]
        if regions: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if get_region_name(device['site']['dns_prefix']) in regions]
        if live == True: netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if device['status'] == 1]

        if output == 'json':
            return netdbDevices
        if output == 'hostname':
            hostnames = []
        for each in netdbDevices['objects']:
            hostnames.append( '%s.%s' % (each['name'], each['site']['dns_prefix']) )
        return hostnames
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks okay to me. I would personally format all those if statements to make everything aligned, to make it easier to read (e.g. align `=`, `if` `in`). Other than that I can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me (except that the last 3 lines need to be indented) and since you say it works, really this is a question for the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) stack.  The only way I might consider changing it is to DRY out the very small amount of repeated logic in the list comprehensions, but really this is a matter of taste. Since my personal taste runs to functions, I might write:

```
def FilterDevices(netdbDevices, values, getter):
     if values:
        netdbDevices['objects'] = [device for device in netdbDevices['objects'] if getter(device) in values]

FilterDevices(netdbDevices, names,   lambda device: device['name'])
FilterDevices(netdbDevices, sites,   lambda device: device['site']['dns_prefix'])
FilterDevices(netdbDevices, models,  lambda device: device['name'].split("-")[0])
FilterDevices(netdbDevices, vendors, lambda device: device['vendor']['name'])
FilterDevices(netdbDevices, regions, lambda device: get_region_name(device['site']['dns_prefix']))
FilterDevices(netdbDevices, [1] if live else [], lambda device: device['status'])
```